# Column does not vertically scroll although it was configured to

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add scrolling behaviour to a `Column` by setting `verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())` modifier.

I checked out some examples in [the official compose-jb repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/examples/imageviewer/common/src/desktopMain/kotlin/example/imageviewer/view/MainScreen.kt#L223), and it seems that that is the right way to do it, yet in my case the content is not scrollable.

Here the full code:

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        // add scroll behaviour
        val stateVertical = rememberScrollState(0)
        Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state = stateVertical)) {
            repeat(100){
                Text("item: $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it does not work in my case?

The Column is populated with 100 `Text` items, more than enough to exceed the default window height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works!

For some reason I was trying to use click and drag... which lead me to confusion.